# Use Webpack to build Angular 2 for NPM Package

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I have a collection of components & services built in Angular 2. Currently they are being bundled and packaged via gulp to a dist folder that is then published on a private npm server. I want to, if possible, stop using Gulp.

My question is, can I use just Webpack to bundle, minify, etc my files to the dist folder. As well as have the ability to run my jasmine tests in them?

I am having trouble getting started. I have a index.ts file that series of exports of all files from each components folder, as well as the main module. Does that become the entry of my webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the file that has all other files as dependencies - is a good candidate for entry, you can also have more that one file as entry to split verdor/your own code to separate js, here the example config (assuming you would use webpack2):

https://github.com/wkwiatek/angular2-webpack2/blob/master/webpack.config.js

This is working version of webpack 2 config

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Allows me to 
                // @Component({
                //    styles: [require('./styles.scss')]
                // })
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "raw-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                // bundle external dependencies to separate file
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                // ts files compilation
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                // Allows me to
                // @Component({
                //     template: require('./template.html')
                // })
                test: /\.html?$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            },
            // stuffs for correct font-awesome loading
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("vendor.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        // inject vendor.css and index.js links into index.html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: conf.path.src('index.html')
        }),
        // workaround for disable warning about critical dependency
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            conf.paths.src
        )
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.ts'
        ]
    },
    // entry point
    entry: `./src/index`,

};
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I want to take the components from my source folder and turn them into js files and put them into a dist folder. I am wondering what kind of loaders I need for that?

Comment: @user2516663 personally i im using ts-loader for typescript, i had poor experience with awesome-typescript-loader - somehow it does't work on windows for my teammates; the other loaders is the matter of choice, but if you interested i can bring working example of webpack2 config

Comment: That would be very helpful. My end goal is to have my components written in Typescript with corresponding sass files end up in the same folder structure but in a dist folder and the files to be .js & .css

Comment: @user2516663  if you target is just to map source files to ready to use files without bundling them together - you would probalby better to stay on existing stack - because the main feature of webpack is packaging, but from your description it looks like you don't want package/join anything

Answer (score 0):

> Webpack is a module bundler. It has nothing to do with a tasks runner, although in many cases can substitute the need of gulp or grunt.

http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2015/10/15/webpack-not-another-task-runner-tool.html

So to answer your questions:

1.) Yes, it can be used to bundle/minify/etc & output to a dist folder.

2.) Running jasmine tests? Webpack doesn't really play a part here. You will likely use an *npm script* to execute tests directly using the jasmine CLI. Unit tests should likely be run on small separate components, not the bundled application as a whole. A decent tutorial here: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-components-in-angular-2-with-jasmine

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely can do these things. In webpack, you would have to specify an entry point.

First, you need to create a file called `webpack.config.js` in the root of your project. This is going to be your `config` file which webpack will try to look into by default.

It looks like this:

> **Note:** This is a webpack 2 implementation

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
  bundle: 'path/to/entry/point' // Note: 'bundle' key will become the name of the bundled file
}

output: {
    path: 'build', // the folder you want your bundle.js to be contained
    filename: '[name].js' // with [name], webpack will automatically look into your entry point key which is 'bundle' in this case
},

// this will tell webpack what files you want to compile and what loaders you would want to use for each
module: {
    rules: [ // from 'loaders' to 'rules'
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
              loader: ['style-loader','sass-loader']
            })
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css') // what the output file (css) is going to be
]}
```

Hope this helps :)